# Как откорректировать работу JS-скрипта?

Tags: javascript

Есть JS-скрипт, который выполняет следующую функцию: когда пользователь делает активными **3 чекбокса**, пользователя перебрасывает на страницу **по сгенерированной чекбоксами** ссылке.

Ссылка формируется из **value=""** трех активированных пользователем чекбоксов, в value помещены отрезки полной ссылки.
Например, в одном "/uslugi", во втором "/remont/", в третьем "remont.html" = site.ru/uslugi/remont/remont.html

Чекбоксы из которых следует захватывать value указаны в скрипте нужным классом.
Теперь сама проблема: когда на странице более 3 элементов одного итого же класса - скрипт почему-то берет value всех чекбоксов, получается каша.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. Нужно чтобы бралось value только активированных пользователем чекбоксов, а остальные, хоть и с тем же классом, не захватывались.

Спасибо!

```
<input id="link1" class="linkinp form-check-input" name="link" type="checkbox" value="/razbito-steklo/">
```

```js
const checks = document.querySelectorAll('input.form-check-input')

checks.forEach(c => c.addEventListener('click', onClick))

function onClick() {
  if ([...checks].filter(c => c.checked).length === 3) {
    const url = 'http://site.ru' + [...checks].map(c => c.value).join('')

   location.href = url
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` не изменяет исходный массив, а создает новый, соответственно там, где вы объединяете значения, вы всё еще работает с исходным массивом, а не отфильтрованным. Присвойте результат фильтрации новой переменный и работайте уже с ней

```js
const checks = document.querySelectorAll('input.form-check-input')

checks.forEach(c => c.addEventListener('click', onClick))

function onClick() {
  const activeChecks = [...checks].filter(c => c.checked);
  if (activeChecks.length === 3) {
    const url = 'http://site.ru' + activeChecks.map(c => c.value).join('')

   console.log(url);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="link1" class="linkinp form-check-input" name="link" type="checkbox" value="/1">
<input id="link1" class="linkinp form-check-input" name="link" type="checkbox" value="/2">
<input id="link1" class="linkinp form-check-input" name="link" type="checkbox" value="/3">
<input id="link1" class="linkinp form-check-input" name="link" type="checkbox" value="/4">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  let checkboxs = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  [...checkboxs].forEach(element => element.onchange = (event) => {
    let count = [...checkboxs].filter(element => element.checked);

    if (count.length === 3) {
      let url = 'https://www.site.ru' + count.map(element => element.getAttribute('value')).join('');
      location.href = url;
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы проверку на `checked` сделали,но в переменную `const url = 'http://site.ru' + [...checks]` пихаете все чекбоксы без фильтрации.

Исправил ваш код:

```js
const checks = document.querySelectorAll('input.form-check-input')

checks.forEach(c => c.addEventListener('click', onClick))

function onClick() {
  if ([...checks].filter(c => c.checked).length === 3) {
    const url = 'http://site.ru' + [...checks].filter(c => c.checked).map(c => c.value).join('')

   location.href = url
  }
}
```